# "I have not been seeing her very often lately"

Tags: present-tense, perfect-constructions

> I have not met her very often lately (that means that I only have seen her once or twice)

BUT if I have seen may be 5 or 6 times can I use

> I **have not been seeing** her very often lately

Comment: You have seen her 5 or 6 times, so you have been seeing her often lately.

Comment: You're not comparing like with like. *I have not met her very often lately* should be compared with *I have not **been meeting** her very often lately*. The problem comes when you compare *I have not seen her very often lately* with *I have not been seeing her very often lately*, where it's not necessarily clear whether *to see her* means ***to go out with her*** (or ***spend time with her***), or simply ***spot her*** (from across the street, perhaps with no personal interaction at all).